# What punctuation should I use here?

Tags: punctuation

> God, do I miss being in Europe **!/.**

Or

> God, do I miss Europe **!/.**

I think both the sentences mean the same thing. What i'm concerned about is what punctuation to put at the end of the sentence.

And one more thing, do the sentences mean the same as "God, I miss being in Europe!", or "God, I miss Europe!"

Comment: The exclamation point adds special emphasis to a sentence, as if you were speaking it quite loud.  The period is more subdued.  Which you want to use is entirely your discretion.

Comment: @Andrew Does, "God, do I miss being in Europe." and, "God, I miss being in Europe." mean the same thing?

Comment: The sentences have similar meanings, but they are not quite the same.  The first one ("I miss being in Europe") connotes the experience of being in Europe.  The second one ("I miss Europe") has a broader connotation and can mean many more things: you miss the culture, and/or food, and/or weather, and/or street signs, and/or any of a thousand other things.

Comment: What Richter65 said is true; however without any other context they both mean more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

In this circumstance it seems that an exclamation point would be the appropriate punctuation.

Regarding whether the sentences mean the same thing, I would say yes they generally do, but they come off slightly differently to me.

When I hear "God, I miss Europe!" I would tend to associate that with you missing the general place **as a whole**.  That is, the culture, food, people etc.  If you said this to me, I would expect our following conversation to be about Europe **as a whole**.  What countries have the best food, beer, etc.

Conversely, "God, I miss being in Europe!" comes off a bit more personally to me.  It sounds as if you miss the specific experiences **you** were having there.  Were you to say "God, I miss being in Europe!" to me, I would expect the follow up conversation to be about things **you** did while you were there.  Specific places you visited, specific meals you ate, people you met, etc.

Comment: Does, "God, I miss being in Europe." mean the same thing as "God, do I miss being in Europe!"

Comment: Generally, yes.  There's a difference in emphasis, but the meaning is the same.